# How do I add count label to an axis?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I created this bar chart using ggplot. I had to create my own count function and called it 'a,' but now the label for that axis just has an a and nothing else... How do I fix it?

```
a <- count(df, glass)

gl <- ggplot(df, aes(x=glass, y="a", fill=glass)) + 
    geom_bar(stat="identity") + 
    theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=90,hjust=1,vjust=0.5)) + 
    xlab("Glass type") + 
    ylab("Count") + 
    coord_flip() + 
    theme_minimal() + 
    theme(legend.position = "none") 
gl
```

Here is my graph
[image: current result]

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: If you want ggplot2 to count things up for you, trying using `geom_bar()` without using `y` at all and then remove `stat = "identity"` from the bar layer.

Answer (score 0):

The default stat value for `geom_bar` is “count”, which means that `geom_bar()` uses `stat_count()` to count the rows of each *x* value, or glass in this case. Using `stat="identity"` will override the default `geom_bar()` stat and require that you provide the *y* values in order for aggregation to occur. I don't believe you are trying to do this.

Try the following and see if it is what you were looking for:

```
gl <- ggplot(df, aes(x=glass, fill=glass)) + 
        geom_bar() + 
        theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=90,hjust=1,vjust=0.5)) + 
        xlab("Glass type") + 
        ylab("Count") + 
        coord_flip() + 
        theme_minimal() + 
        theme(legend.position = "none")
```